# Write zlib compressed utf8 data to a file

Tags: python, utf-8, zlib

I have a file with data encoded in utf-8. I would like to read the data, remove whitespaces, separate words with a newline, compress the entire content and write them to a file. This is what I am trying to do :

```
with codecs.open('1020104_4.utf8', encoding='utf8', mode='r') as fr :
    data = re.split(r'\s+',fr.read().encode('utf8'))
    #with codecs.open('out2', encoding='utf8', mode='w') as fw2 :
        data2 = ('\n'.join(data)).decode('utf8')
        data3 = zlib.compress(data2)
        #fw2.write(data3)
```

However I get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tmp2.py", line 17, in <module>
        data3 = zlib.compress(data2)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 47-48: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I write this data to a file?

Comment: You are trying to write zlib compressed data as UTF-8. The compressed data is not text anymore, so this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. And regarding the compression, what can I do to make zlib compress the UTF-8 string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your encoding-foo is just the wrong way round, in Python 3 this would be a lot clearer ☺.

First, when splitting you want to do this on *decoded*  data, i.e. on Unicode strings, which you already get from `read` since you are using `codecs.open`, so the first line should be

```
data = re.split(r'\s+', fr.read())
```

Consequently, before passing data to `zlib` you want to convert it to `bytes` by *encoding* it:

```
data2 = ('\n'.join(data)).encode('utf8')
data3 = zlib.compress(data2)
```

In the last step you want to write it to a *binary* file handle:

```
with open("output", "wb") as fw:
    fw.write(data3)
```

You can shorten this a bit by using the `gzip` module instead:

```
with codecs.open('1020104_4.utf8', encoding='utf8', mode='r') as fr:
    data = re.split(r'\s+', fr.read())
    with gzip.open('out2', mode='wb') as fw2 :
        data2 = ('\n'.join(data)).encode('utf8')
        fw2.write(data2)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is going to be very useful for me.